# I added a timefield in a model in django, when I applied migrations there was an error, when I removed that field in the model there still was error

Tags: python, django, mysql-python

Error:

```
Operations to perform:
Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions, tohome
Running migrations:
Applying tohome.0003_auto_20210323_1611...Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
main()
File "manage.py", line 18, in main
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "C:\Users\madhu\Desktop\Django work\work_env\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "C:\Users\madhu\Desktop\Django work\work_env\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
 File "C:\Users\madhu\Desktop\Django work\work_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", 
 line 330, in run_from_argv       
 self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
 File "C:\Users\madhu\Desktop\Django work\work_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", 
 line 371, in execute
 output = self.handle(*args, **options)
 File "C:\Users\madhu\Desktop\Django work\work_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", 
 line 85, in wrapped
 res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
 File "C:\Users\madhu\Desktop\Django work\work_env\lib\site- 
 packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 245, in handle  
 fake_initial=fake_initial,
 File "C:\Users\madhu\Desktop\Django work\work_env\lib\site- 
 packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
 File "C:\Users\madhu\Desktop\Django work\work_env\lib\site- 
packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
File "C:\Users\madhu\Desktop\Django work\work_env\lib\site- 
packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 227, in apply_migration   
state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
File "C:\Users\madhu\Desktop\Django work\work_env\lib\site- 
packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 124, in apply
operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "C:\Users\madhu\Desktop\Django work\work_env\lib\site- 
packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 106, in database_forwards
field,
```

)
File "C:\Users\madhu\Desktop\Django work\work_env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\dateparse.py", line
90, in parse_time
match = time_re.match(value)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

models.py

```
from django.db import models
    class Task(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length =200)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default = False , blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    settime = models.TimeField((""), auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)


    def __str__(self):
      return self.title
```

Comment: The migration file still contains the old field. So you will have to remove that field, and recreate migrations.

Comment: What's an argument you have in `TimeField` - `("")`. How you expect it to work?